# What is the current size of the blockchain?

Tags: node

What is the current size of the blockchain? Is there a site that tracks this quantity in real time? I only see sporadic numbers around (e.g [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/9lc7by/tezos_blockchain_size_3_months_16_gigabytes/)), which seem to be calculated from someone already running a node. Yet, for someone not currently running a node (and perhaps interested in running one), this method is unhelpful.

Also, I read that [there is a plan](https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-snapshots-and-history-modes-for-the-tezos-node.html) to limit the actual size of the blockchain users need to have. Although this is clearly not implemented yet, it would be useful to also have a real time measure of the "effective" size of the blockchain needed to run a node.

Comment: You can use the mainnet-snapshots branch already. See here https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-snapshots-and-history-modes-for-the-tezos-node.html . Right now in full archive mode the chain takes between 90GB and 100GB on my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

At 2019-03-19T05:27:36Z current size of ./tezos-node folder , practical size of blockchain is 107.3 GB

Comment: That's not the size of the chain, that's the size of all intermediate contexts.