# Archive node size

Tags: node, archive-node

At March it was [107.3 GB](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/816/what-is-the-current-size-of-the-blockchain).

What is the current archive node data size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm running an archive node with the new Irmin2 backend, currently (block level 651397, October 15th 2019), it uses 37G, with 26G for the historical contexts and 11G for the blocks and operations store.

```
$ ./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/header | egrep "level|timestamp"
  "level": 651397, "proto": 4,
  "timestamp": "2019-10-15T12:40:04Z", "validation_pass": 4,
```

```
$ du -hc ~/.tezos-node
11G     /home/ubuntu/.tezos-node/store
7.7G    /home/ubuntu/.tezos-node/context/index
26G     /home/ubuntu/.tezos-node/context
37G     /home/ubuntu/.tezos-node
37G     total
```